# JQuery Datatables & ColdFusion - How do I get the array source data in that format?

Tags: jquery, ajax, arrays, coldfusion, datatables

I'm following the example on this page to setup an Ajax source for JQuery Datatables.
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html

I can recreate this just fine if I start out with the source file just like their example array, in the following format.

```
{
  "aaData": [
    {
       "engine": "Trident",
       "browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
       "platform": "Win 95+",
       "version": "4",
       "grade": "X"
    },
    {
       "engine": "Trident",
       "browser": "Internet Explorer 5.0",
       "platform": "Win 95+",
       "version": "5",
       "grade": "C"
    }
  ]
 }
```

However, I'm using ColdFusion and I want my source data to come from a query.  So, I followed another example about populating an array from a cfquery.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec09f0b-7fea.html

That will put my sample data array in the following format.

```
RecordID: 2, Name: Al
RecordID: 1, Name: Mike
RecordID: 3, Name: Bill
```

What can I do to run a cfquery that will populate my source file in the proper format needed for the sAjaxSource attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the replies.  I ended up using pieces of a some code I found online to get this to work.

This is my source table (DataSource.cfm)

```
<cfquery name="Query1" datasource="x">
    Select RecordID, NAME
    From TestTable
</cfquery>

<cfset data = [] />

<cfoutput query="Query1">
    <cfset obj = {
        "RecordID" = RecordID,
        "NAME" = Name
     } />
    <cfset arrayAppend(data, obj) />
</cfoutput>


<cfprocessingdirective suppresswhitespace="Yes">
    <cfoutput>
        {"aaData":
        #serializeJSON(data)#
        }
    </cfoutput>
</cfprocessingdirective>

<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="No" showdebugoutput="No">
```

and this is the JQuery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": false,
    "sAjaxSource": "DataSource.cfm",
    "aoColumns": [
         { "mData": "RecordID" },
         { "mData": "NAME" }
    ]
         });
    });
 </script>
```

and here's the body of the page

```
<form>
        <div id ="div1" class="dataTables_wrapper">
            <table id="example">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>RecordID</th>
                        <th>NAME</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: nice job detailing this answer, thanks. Works perfectly. Now all I need to do is tweak it to make it an editable table.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a [JSON converter specifically for this](https://github.com/iknowkungfoo/cfquery-to-json/blob/master/DataTables.md):

```
<cfset rs.dt = new DataTables() />
<cfset rs.dt.setData( yourQuery ) /> <!--- yourQuery = ColdFusion query --->
<cfset rs.dt.setDataFormat( "struct" ) />
<cfreturn rs.dt.$renderData() />
```

Converts your ColdFusion query into the jQuery DataTables format.

DataTables.cfc requires ArrayCollection.cfc, which is in the same repository.

Comment: The KungFoo sample apps (there are two) are helpful resources to learn from, thanks for sharing.

Comment: You even provided an apache-derby db and provide a link to a db viewer! Awesome-ness!

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a variable that is a structure (lets call it `myVar`).
2. Create a key in that structure named `appData` and set it to an empty array.
3. Loop over the query and inside the loop, create a structure (lets call it `myStruct`)
4. Still inside the loop, create keys for `myStruct` named `engine`, `browser`, etc. and populate these keys based on the relative data in your query row.
5. Still inside the loop, append `myStruct` to the `myVar.appData` array.
6. After the loop, `myVar` should have a structure similar to your example, if it does not, you made an error somewhere.